# Invalid configuration with login social media yii2

Tags: authentication, yii2, token, configuration-files

When I have token "Client Id" and "Client Secret" google, facebook, twitter and GitHub. I finished configuration file Collection.php in directory[[yii\authclient\Collection]]. And then I configuration which part "component". For that scrip this bellow :

````html
<?php
/**
 * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
 * @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
 */

namespace yii\authclient;

use yii\base\Component;
use yii\base\InvalidParamException;
use yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice;
use yii\authclient\Collection;
use \yii\authclient\AuthAction;
use Yii;


 //Collection is a storage for all auth clients in the application.
 
 // Example application configuration:
 
 // ```php
 'components' => [
     'authClientCollection' => [
         'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
         'clients' => [
             'google' => [
                 'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\GoogleOAuth',
                 'clientId' => 'example',
                 'clientSecret' => 'example',
              ],
             'facebook' => [
                 'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Facebook',
                 'clientId' => 'example',
                 'clientSecret' => 'example',
             ],
             'twitter' => [
                 'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Twitter',
                 'consumerKey' => 'example',
                 'consumerSecret' => 'example',
             ],
             'github' => [
                 'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Github',
                 'clientId' => 'example',
                 'clientSecret' => 'example',
             ],
         ],
     ]
 ]
 
 // @property ClientInterface[] $clients List of auth clients. This property is read-only.
 // @author Paul Klimov <klimov.paul@gmail.com>
 // @since 2.0
 // 
class Collection extends Component
{
    /**
     * @var \yii\httpclient\Client|array|string HTTP client instance or configuration for the [[clients]].
     * If set, this value will be passed as 'httpClient' config option while instantiating particular client object.
     * This option is useful for adjusting HTTP client configuration for the entire list of auth clients.
     */
    public $httpClient;

    /**
     * @var array list of Auth clients with their configuration in format: 'clientId' => [...]
     */
    private $_clients = [];


    /**
     * @param array $clients list of auth clients
     */
    public function setClients(array $clients)
    {
        $this->_clients = $clients;
    }

    /**
     * @return ClientInterface[] list of auth clients.
     */
    public function getClients()
    {
        $clients = [];
        foreach ($this->_clients as $id => $client) {
            $clients[$id] = $this->getClient($id);
        }

        return $clients;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $id service id.
     * @return ClientInterface auth client instance.
     * @throws InvalidParamException on non existing client request.
     */
    public function getClient($id)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($id, $this->_clients)) {
            throw new InvalidParamException("Unknown auth client '{$id}'.");
        }
        if (!is_object($this->_clients[$id])) {
            $this->_clients[$id] = $this->createClient($id, $this->_clients[$id]);
        }

        return $this->_clients[$id];
    }

    /**
     * Checks if client exists in the hub.
     * @param string $id client id.
     * @return boolean whether client exist.
     */
    public function hasClient($id)
    {
        return array_key_exists($id, $this->_clients);
    }

    /**
     * Creates auth client instance from its array configuration.
     * @param string $id auth client id.
     * @param array $config auth client instance configuration.
     * @return ClientInterface auth client instance.
     */
    protected function createClient($id, $config)
    {
        $config['id'] = $id;

        if (!isset($config['httpClient']) && $this->httpClient !== null) {
            $config['httpClient'] = $this->httpClient;
        }

        return Yii::createObject($config);
    }
}
````

After that, I put script for link login social media in bellow button login. 
for that script this  :

```
<?= yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice::widget(['baseAuthUrl' => ['site/auth'] ]); ?>
```

For result in browser : 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlrOI.png)

**config/web.php**

```
<?php

    $params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

    $config = [
        'id' => 'basic',
        'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
        'bootstrap' => ['log'],
        'components' => [
            'authClientCollection' => [
             'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
             'clients' => [
                 'google' => [
                     'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\GoogleOAuth',
                     'clientId' => 'example',
                     'clientSecret' => 'example,
                  ],
                 'facebook' => [
                     'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Facebook',
                     'clientId' => 'example',
                     'clientSecret' => 'example',
                 ],
                 'twitter' => [
                     'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Twitter',
                     'consumerKey' => 'example',
                     'consumerSecret' => 'example',
                 ],
                 'github' => [
                     'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Github',
                     'clientId' => 'example',
                     'clientSecret' => 'example',
                 ],
               ],
            ],
            'request' => [
                // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
                'cookieValidationKey' => 'K1pkkP_iwACp933A03LotJ3AfRsyIb-D',
            ],
            'cache' => [
                'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
            ],
            'user' => [
                'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
                'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            ],
            'errorHandler' => [
                'errorAction' => 'site/error',
            ],
            'mailer' => [
                'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
                // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
                // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
                // for the mailer to send real emails.
                'useFileTransport' => true,
            ],
            'log' => [
                'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
                'targets' => [
                    [
                        'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                        'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
            'urlManager' => [
                'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                'showScriptName' => false,
                ],
        ],
        'modules' => [
           // 'gii' => 'yii\gii\Module',
            'reportico' => [
                'class' => 'reportico\reportico\Module' ,
                'controllerMap' => [
                                'reportico' => 'reportico\reportico\controllers\ReporticoController',
                                'mode' => 'reportico\reportico\controllers\ModeController',
                                'ajax' => 'reportico\reportico\controllers\AjaxController',
                            ]
                ],
            ],  
        'modules' => ['admin' => ['class' => 'app\modules\admin\Module'],],


        'params' => $params,
    ];

    $config['modules']['gridview'] = [
    'class'=>'\kartik\grid\Module',
    ];

    if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
        // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
        $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
        $config['modules']['debug'] = [
            'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        ];

        $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
        $config['modules']['gii'] = [
            'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        ];
    }

    return $config;
```

Comment: Maybe silly question but have you got `yiisoft/yii2-authclient` added to your composer.json?

Comment: No in composer.json, but in file @app/views/site/login.php

Comment: So there is no extension installed? You need to install it first.

Comment: Extension is installed

Comment: try `'class' => yii\authclient\Collection::className(),`

Comment: Can you paste your whole configuration file?

Comment: I've try for 'class' => yii\authclient\Collection::className(), and nonetheless.

Comment: show `config/web.php` if basic else show `common/main.php`